# Create search box like Material Design 2018

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to create in an Android Studio project a search box that it's like Google Maps app search box. How can I do that? Is there a sample to reproduce it?
Thanks in advise

This is the
[Search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niNSG.png)

Comment: Yes, you can create using cardview.
its easily created using Cardlayout and its elevation.

Comment: Have you checked [material.io](https://material.io/develop/android/) They've components which you can use

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil I checked this https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android, but I didn't find it

Comment: @clooock this -> https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `FrameLayout` as search box and replace it with a custom `Fragment`.

This is a sample code for the search box that you attached.

Search box **Fragment Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/search_box_style"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dehaze_black_24dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_black_24dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*you can use your components in `Fragment`.*

**search_box_style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="0.1dp"
        android:color="#7b7b7b" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

And you can set `Listeners` for your `Fragment` items.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will do it in this way!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating everything yourself which kind of is reinventing the wheel, you can use [this](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview) open source library which not only let you create searchview easily but also allows you to style it and have many other options that are complex to access when do it all yourself.
Here is a screenshot showing what this lib can do:

[image]

Otherwise, you can use Android [searchview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView) component, set some background and add styling to make it look as you want.